# How to get Full Screen Caller id?

Tags: sync, nexus-4, google-plus, caller-id, contact-photo

In my Nexus 4 i have successfully synced the contacts with their google plus and assigned them with their profile picture. The issue is when i call them (outgoing calls) i am able to get their pic in full screen. But when i receive calls (incoming calls) the pic is displayed partly at the top of the screen. What is the issue and how to solve this?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot to make it clear what you mean by "the pic is displayed partly at the top of the screen"?

Comment: Partly in the sense Image is displayed for the top half of the screen and attend/cut option in the bottom half of the screen. I Just want to show the image in full screen and attend/cut option to be over the image. (Sorry i could not attach screenshot now).

Answer (score 0):

That is because this is a stock android feature. To accomplish the result you want you'll need some kind of third party software i geuss. There are lots available in the play store.